# Returning binary across cores through shards in Solr

Tags: java, solr, binary

I am currently searching multiple cores at a time though the use of shards in Solr. We store some content as encoded binary (base64) so that we can use it but not let it be searchable. Whenever we search the core where the index is stored directly the binary is returned properly and we can decode it and use it however we want. When we search the core using shards however the binary is returned in the following format:

```
[B:[B@26b8320f
```

There is consistently `[B:[B@` followed by a short string of letters and numbers. All other content that is not stored in binary is returned as normal. I believe this is an address of some sort but am not sure. I am unable to decode this to use the content it holds. Any idea how to decode this? Or make it usable in it's current format? We are currently running Solr 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the default `toString()` method of `byte[]`. it contains the class type `[B:[B` and its hashcode (which is the address in this case). You need to decode it, probably with the same library / package you used to encode it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although this didn't specifically answer the question in regards to Solr, it did give me a place to look for the answer. I found an update to Solr 4.x that fixed this issue and was able to update Solr 3.6 with the same update. [4.x Pull Request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3035) that I found.